# I need some guidence trying to work through an algebra example

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The example i am having trouble with is :

```
1 + x / 3 + x = 0.4
```

The answer that fits there is 0.3333333 but i cant workout how to get it. I am trying to learn algebra, and i can do simple equations but not this one.

I see that the two x's could be like terms.

Following the PEMDAS rule i am meant to do the divison first, as the are no parenthesis.

And i see that 1 / 3 gives the answer of 0.333333 but obviously that cant be the way to solved the equation

Can i please have some guidence

Comment: are you saying the 1 is divided by 3 like $(1+x)/3$?

Comment: That's the example i was given. I assumed it would be like (1 + x )/ 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to solve $1 + \frac{x}{3} + x = 0.4$, then add the last two terms, giving $1 + \frac{4}{3}x = 0.4$, so that $\frac{4}{3}x = -0.6$. I assume you can take it from there.

However, if you think the correct answer is $\frac{1}{3}\approx 0.33333...$, then I suspect the problem you are trying to solve is $\frac{1+x}{3+x} = 0.4$:
\begin{align}
  \frac{1+x}{3+x} &= 0.4 \\
  1+x &= 1.2 + 0.4x \\
  0.6x &= 0.2 \\
  x &= \frac{1}{3}.
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you Roger, i think you're right that the problem is indeed how you wrote it in the second answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem you're trying to solve is
$$
\frac{1+x}{3+x} = 0.4
$$
That's different from 
$$
1 + x/3 + x = 0.4
$$
which is a sum of three terms instead of a quotient of two.

When you have a quotient, like
$$
\frac{A}{B} = 0.4
$$
often the best thing to do is multiply both side by the denominator, to get

$$
B\frac{A}{B} = B\cdot 0.4
$$
Now the left hand side simplifies to just $A$, and you have 
$$
A = B \cdot 0.4.
$$
In your case, this looks like this:

$$
\frac{1+x}{3+x} = 0.4 \\
(3+x) \frac{1+x}{3+x} = (3 + x) \cdot 0.4 \\
1+x = (3 + x) \cdot 0.4 \\
1+x = 1.2 + 0.4x \\
$$
Now move everything to one side (by subtracting 1+x from both sides) to get
$$
0 = 1.2 + 0.4x - (1+x) \\
0 = 1.2 + 0.4x - 1-x \\
0 = 0.2 + 0.4x -x \\
0 = 0.2 - 0.6x
$$
and bringing the 0.6x to the other side, get
$$
0.6x = 0.2
\\
x = 0.2/0.6 = 0.3333...
$$

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer john

Comment: @bezzzo  you can upvote an answer if you like it.

Comment: @THE LONE WOLF unfortunately i cant as i don't have the required 15 reputation points to do so.